# Play Framework: BodyParser that returns 400 if exception is thrown during JSON parsing

Tags: playframework

The default json `BodyParser` returns a 500 if an exception was thrown during JSON parsing - e.g. if there is a `require(…)` and some condition wasn’t met. I would like to make this scenario return a 400. How can I extend the default JSON `BodyParser` to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom `BodyParser` which handles (specific?) exceptions when parsing the request body:

```scala
val exceptionalJsonParser = BodyParser { h =>
  try {
    parse.tolerantJson(h) // <- call your normal parser here
  } catch {
    // catching all non-fatal exceptions here might not be a good idea,
    // be more specific !
    case NonFatal(e) => Accumulator.done(Left(BadRequest(e.getMessage)))
  }
}

def action = Action.async(exceptionalJsonParser) { 
  ... 
}
```